# Return data from submitted form targeted to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, file-upload, web.py

I have a web.py application with which i have implemented a form that uploads a file to my server via post with the target set as an iframe in my page. This works a charm but I want to be able to send some data bak to the page that I submitted from about the file that i uploaded; when it is uploaded there may be a file with he same name that exists so i will rename it and i want to display that name on the page without the need for a refresh. I could sent return some text in the body of the iframe that i parse for the data but that seems like a messy way to do things.

How would you normally handle this?

Comment: Without a callback on the iframe you would need to send a get request to the server after the form is submitted.  This would be done on form submit, but perhaps with a timeout(). Serve data as jsonp if it is cross-browser.  It would work, but either way it's messy.

Comment: in your opinion is it messy bad or messy but has to be done?

Comment: If that is the only option then it has to be done. I have used this technique when posting to a remote server. In my case it was posting to a Google spreadsheet and wanted to do so without a reload. It worked well and was my only option, messy or not.